# I used my ntfs formatted hard drive, copied files from a Mac using a bridge program, but now I can't see any of the files on my PC help?

Tags: windows, macos, ntfs

I used my NTFS formatted hard drive, copied files from a Mac using a bridge program, but now I can't see any of the files on my PC help?

I brought it from home, (NTFS hard drive) found that it was only read only.. so I got a bridge program (don't remember) and was able to copy files from the Mac to the hard drive. I took it home and went to get into those files, and they do not even show up.. it copied, and did everything it was supposed to do to let me know it was working, but now I can't find any of those files.

Comment: Have you checked if the files were written onto the hdd after the copy process?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a file permissions/ownership issue.  Are you running XP Pro or Vista or Win7?  If so you should be able to go to the root of the drive and take ownership of all files, forcing inheritance and propogation.  If the amount that you copied is largeish, you could check the size of the drive and the available free space just to verify that the files are at least taking up space on the drive before digging in to try to find them.